# Data mining on unstructured text

Tags: mongodb, data-mining

I am working right now at a academic project and I want to use data mining tehniques for a market segmentetion.

I want to store text information (which is supossed to be large amount of text), like tweets, news feed etc - so they are different source of data (they have different structure).

There are 2 questions:

1. What is the best way to get all this news articles, posts etc, so I can finally get enough text data to have the posibility to process it and to draw good conclusions from it? Or what other kind of unstructured data cand I use?
2. Where to store all the unstructured text, in order to access it later and apply all this text mining tehniques? What about MongoDB?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following:

- [Apache Lucene](https://lucene.apache.org/core/)
- [Apache Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/)
- [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch)